# The most common way to load UIImage from the web

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa

Dear stackoverflowers,

I have gone astray.

In my app I load 2 images from the web, like this:

```
-(void)loadImages
{
  ...

  image1 = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imgUrl1]];
  image2 = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imgUrl2]];
}
```

In order to not blocking the main thread, I use **GCD**:

```
dispatch_async( dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0), ^{
            [self loadImages];
```

After that, I use these images in my `UITableView`:

```
if (indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        cell.imageView.image = image1;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.imageView.image = image2;
    }
```

Then I decided to add `UIActivityIndicator`, but faced some problems. I understand that my code is not correct. I saw that people using `NSURLRequest` and `NSURLConnection` to load images and add `UIActivityIndicator`.

Could you tell me please, what is the most standart way to load images like that ? What should I rewrite ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you to use AsyncImageView a beautiful implementation by Nicklockwood -father of iCarousel.

https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView

it is very simple to use.

```
    #import "AsyncImageView.h"
```

and in all imageViews do this.

```
    [imageView setImage:@"default.png"];
    [imageView setImageURL:@"whateverurl/whateverimage.png"];
```

In your case it would be:
      [cell.imageView setImageURL:@"yourURL"];

It works like a charm, and my code is in production. But if you still want your code to work try this:

```
 UIActivityIndicator *activity =[[UIActivityIndicator alloc] initWithStyle:UIActivityIndicatorWhite];
 [activity setFrame:CGRectMake(100,100,30,30)];
 [self.view addSubview:activity];

 dispatch_queue_t dispatchQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);
 dispatch_async(dispatchQueue, ^(void)
 { 
  [activity startAnimating];
 [self loadImages];
 dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ 
 [yourTableView reloadData];
 [activity stopAnimating];
 [activty setHidden:YES];
 });
 });
```

Comment: Did you try my implementation? Did it work? Upvote or accept if you are cool with my ans.

Answer (score 2):

I can tell you what I usually do if I want to use my own custom code

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
    NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:_pictureURL];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    });
});
```

Otherwise you can consider the [`UIImageView+AFNetworking`](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/UIImageView+AFNetworking.m) category that adds the method

```
setImageWithURLRequest:placeholderImage:success:failure:
```

to `UIImageView`.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code (assuming that you've confirmed that it works).  Just because others use NSURLConnection and related doesn't make yours wrong.

To use the activity indicator do this:

```
-(void)loadImages
{
  UIActivityIndicator *indicator = ...

  ...
  [indicator startAnimating];
  image1 = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imgUrl1]];
  image2 = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imgUrl2]];
  [indicator stopAnimating];
}
```

Small nit - personally I'd use:

```
   cell.imageView.image = (0 == indexPath.row ? image1 : image2)
```

as nobody seems to appreciate the C 'conditional expressoin'.  End small nit.

Comment: Thanks GoZoner ! But I have no idea how can I use UIActivityIndicator in this case, because I don't know when an image is loaded, so I can stop the indicator's animation. I saw that if you use NSURLConnection you can use standart methods such as 
`-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection*)theConnection` and find out when image is loaded.

Thanks for the nit, I didn't think of that.

Comment: `dataWithContentsOfURL:` is a synchronous method. This code would block the UI.

Comment: Even if called in a dispatch_async()?

Comment: inside a `dispatch_async` no, you're right (I missed the fact that loadImage is called inside it. Stil this will retrieve the images in sequence, whereas is more efficient to spawn a thread for every image request.

Comment: +Erway Software, where is it on the main thread?  Did you read the OP and see where `loadImages` is being called?