# Asynchronous Image loading from JSON in iOS

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I have been trying to make images load from a JSON feed asynchronously, using AFNetworking. However every example with that library, or any others, seems to only load the images asynchronously, but not the links from the JSON feed for the images. As seen in the documentation for AFNetworking, nothing asynchronous is ever mentioned about the JSON feed.

What I always end up being stuck with is loading 10-15 images at a time, then having to load more once the user gets down to the bottom of my UICollectionView. This takes time, since all 15 images have to be loaded from the JSON feed.

Is there an example somewhere out there that I can actually follow? If there is not, is there a better way to do infinite scroll other than scrollViewDidEndDecelerating?

or is the point of the asynchronous image loading in afnetworking to load the the links from the json using an infinite scrolling method, and then load the images asynchronously after that point?

I guess what I am looking for is a smooth infinite scroll with asynchronous image loading for my uicollectionview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try AsyncImageView, check out [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15865809/the-most-common-way-to-load-uiimage-from-the-web/15865956#15865956) it might quite suite your need.