# Application Crash on Fast switching between UISegment

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios5, ios6

I have a segment and a table view, I have to reload the data in the table view its working but when i switch the segment buttons fast then application crashes.

On segment i have three buttons and on their action I am triggering a request to a url and fetching the json from that url (3 different urls resp. and returns 10, 17 and 8 results in json).

I have a custom table cell which have the images in it and i am trying to lazily load theose images.

In JSON result each object of json have various keys in it like name, id, imageurl etc.

the id is unique throughout the application and I am trying to load the images and save the images in local memory based on that unique id, so that i can show the cashed images and no need to redownload the images on segment change because some enteries on all three segments are same.

Here is my complete code

```
- (IBAction)segmentedControlIndexChanged {
NSString *offerRequestUrl = nil;
switch (self.mySegment.selectedSegmentIndex) {
    case 0:
        offerRequestUrl = @"url_one";
        self.feedRequestUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:offerRequestUrl];
        break;
    case 1:
        offerRequestUrl = @"url_two";;
        self.feedRequestUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:offerRequestUrl];
        break;
    case 2:
        offerRequestUrl = @"url_three";;
        self.feedRequestUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:offerRequestUrl];
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
  [self parseJSONWithURL:self.feedRequestUrl];
}
- (void) parseJSONWithURL:(NSURL *) jsonURL
 {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: jsonURL];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
    });
}

- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {
//parse out the json data
NSError* error;
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                                                     options:kNilOptions
                                                       error:&error];

self.feedsArray = [json objectForKey:@"result"];
[self.myTableView reloadData];
 }

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
 int count = self.feedsArray.count;

// if there's no data yet, return enough rows to fill the screen
if (count == 0)
{
    return 1;
}
return count;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {

// customize the appearance of table view cells
//
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyTableCell";
static NSString *PlaceholderCellIdentifier = @"PlaceholderCell";

// add a placeholder cell while waiting on table data
int nodeCount = [self.feedsArray count];

if (nodeCount == 0 && indexPath.row == 0)
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:PlaceholderCellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                      reuseIdentifier:PlaceholderCellIdentifier];
        cell.detailTextLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }

    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Loading . . .";

    [self performSelector:@selector(checkAndDisplayAlert) withObject:self afterDelay:10.0];

    return cell;
}

CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (nodeCount > 0)
{        
    // Configure the cell...
    cell.carImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Placeholder"]; //acts as default image
    if([self.imageDict  valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.feedsArray[indexPath.row][@"id_str"]]]==nil)
    {
        [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(displayingSmallImage:) toTarget:self withObject:indexPath];
    } else {
        cell.carImageView.image = [self.imageDict valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.feedsArray[indexPath.row][@"id_str"]]];
    }

    cell.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    cell.titleLabel.text = self.feedsArray[indexPath.row][@"title_key"];

}
return cell;
 }

  - (void) displayingSmallImage:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSString *imageUrl = self.feedsArray[indexPath.row][@"icon_url"];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];
if(image == nil)
{
    image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Placeholder"]];
}
[self.imageDict setObject:image forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.feedsArray[indexPath.row][@"id_str"]]];
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(imageReceived:) withObject:indexPath waitUntilDone:NO];
  }

   - (void) imageReceived:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
UIImage *image = (UIImage *)[self.imageDict objectForKey: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.feedsArray[indexPath.row][@"id_str"]]];
UIImageView *imgs = (UIImageView *)[[self.myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] viewWithTag:IMG_TAG];
[imgs setImage:image];
[self.myTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
  }

  - (void) checkAndDisplayAlert
{
if (!self.feedsArray && self.isAlertPresent == NO) {
    UIAlertView *nilAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sorry!"
                                                       message:@"No result returned from server."
                                                      delegate:self
                                             cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                             otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [nilAlert setTag:kNilAlertTag];
    self.isAlertPresent = YES;
    [nilAlert show];
}
 }
```

The main things I have to do is

1. lazily download the images
2. cache the images in local memory based on unique ID
3. Check the cashed images dictionary for already downloaded image and display it
4. If possible save these downloaded images in the local memory (nsuserdefaults etc) so that       if user restart the app then also images are there and can be displayed based on their unique ID and no need to download again.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe I'm not completely following... aren't the four "main things you have to do" exactly what you need to accomplish your goal(s)? Have you tried to implement any of those yet?

Comment: Yes i am trying top three but application is crashing.

Comment: Care to share the dump of where it's crashing? On a side note a super-lazy way to bandaid this would be to disable the UITabBar buttons until the initial loads are done. That way when you get around to figuring out #4 you're good to go. Again... that's pure bandaid.

Comment: goes in main and now its throwing the error *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (3) beyond bounds (3)'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1615012 0x143ae7e 0x1614deb 0x16097e0 0x168e3a8 0xadc6 0xe85805 0xe85764 0x95b065b7 0x95af0d4e)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

Answer (score 0):

Please post the error log, if it is array out of bounds exception I suspect these two methods

```
- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData & your tableViewDatasource
```

To find which line of code causes this crash do this. Go to break points tab on the left side and click + in the bottom.

[image]

Then you would get something like this:

[image]

Just hit done, run your code again and tell us which line caused the exception.

I understood your problem, why do you want to take the URL from the array in this function

```
  - (void) displayingSmallImage:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

you could pass the Url to load to that function, from cellForRowAtIndex like this:

```
    NSArray *argsToPass=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath,self.feedsArray[indexPath.row][@"icon_url"]];

    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(displayingSmallImage:) toTarget:self withObject:argsToPass];
```

and your function is modified as:

```
 - (void) displayingSmallImage:(NSArray *)args
{

  if([args count] == 0)
 {
NSString *imageUrl = [args objectAtIndex:1];

NSIndexPath *indexPath=[args objectAtIndex:0]; 

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];
if(image == nil)
{
    image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Placeholder"]];
}
[self.imageDict setObject:image forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.feedsArray[indexPath.row][@"id_str"]]];
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(imageReceived:) withObject:indexPath waitUntilDone:NO];
  }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll follow this method and share the result in a while

Comment: The control is in                  - (void) displayingSmallImage:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 method and on line         [self.imageDict setObject:image forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.feedsArray[indexPath.row][@"id_str"]]];
showing a sigabert error

Comment: From what your code says you are trying to access a dictionary from a array of dictionaries right?. I guess the problem is with your self.feedsArray, it does not contain object at the passed index.

Comment: I see that you try to lazy load images and also you want to cache them locally, See my previous answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15865809/the-most-common-way-to-load-uiimage-from-the-web/15865956#15865956 about loading images asynchronously.

Comment: feeds array is updated every time when i trigger a web-service request and few values/objects are same in all three JSON response but the id is unique and same for all three and all text gets changed properly but during image download or display its crashing and it only crashes on fast switching between segment on a average switching speed through segment it working fine but crashing on fast switching only.

Comment: I understand your problem when switching between your segments the function   [self parseJSONWithURL:self.feedRequestUrl]; is not being cancelled for the previous segment and also the current thread is running, the array values are changed by the previous thread and the numberOfRows method returns that count then in the tableviewdatasource the array contains values updated by current thread so that makes the exception. Try setting userInteration of the segment to FALSE when the loading is in process.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to check and cancel the current download progress, but I have to keep the segment's user interaction enabeled all the time

Comment: See my answer I have edited the last part, modify like that it should work.

Comment: I am getting all the image urls in args array but the placeholder image is not getting set and also From where to get the indexpath.row in line                        [self.imageDict setObject:image forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.feedsArray[indexPath.row][@"id_str"]]];   in the method - (void) displayingSmallImage:(NSArray *)args

Answer (score 0):

you can set  self.view.userInteractionEnabled=NO when you are sending request to server.
and when u get the data just enable the user interaction .so that multiple requests are avoided.